# rxjs emmit values only after another observable completes

Tags: rxjs

I have working pieace of code:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

const stream$ = of(3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3);

const ready$ = stream$.pipe(takeWhile((data) => data !== 0));

ready$.subscribe(console.log)
```

It will log 3, 2, 1.

How to create an observable that emmits all `$stream` values but only after `0` is emmited.

In other words: when `ready$` completes, how to have observable that emmits values of `stream$` except 3, 2, 1, 0?

Comment: You'll need to share the source observable and also convert them into connectable observales so that you can connect them before you subscribe (sharing synchronous obseravles can be a bit tricky).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace `takeWhile` with `skipWhile` and add an extra `skip(1)` to ignore 0

```
const ready$ = stream$.pipe(skipWhile((data) => data !== 0),skip(1));
```